# Fix regex to extract specific number formats

Tags: ruby, regex

Ideally my regex should capture/extract all the following number formats:

500 /
500.55 /
500k /
500.55k /
500 to 600 /
500k to 600k /
500 to 600k /
500.55 to 600.55 /
500.55 to 600.55 k

I have a problem with my current regex, because if numbers like "700,000" or "800,000" or "8.54" are in the text then it splits up the numbers and captures:

```
700,000 => "700","000"
800,000. => "800" , "000." , "8.", "54" 
8.54 => "8.", "54"
```

Any ideas what to change? Current regex:

```
(\d+(?:\.?\d*)?\s*k?(?:\-|to)\s*\d+(?:\.?\d*)\s*k?|\d+(?:\.?\d*)\s*k?)
```

Comment: Just to precise: you still need `500 to 600` as `500 to 600`, not as separate numbers, right?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen with input like `"700,000"`, `"800,000."` or `"8.54"`?

Comment: Try `/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?:\s*k)?(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?:\s*k)?)?/i`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes if there is a format like 500 to 600 then it should capture the whole only and not separately the numbers

Comment: Good, I provided my regex below. I guess you use it with `scan`, so I decided not to shorten it with `\g<1>` to repeat the first `\d+(?:[.,]\d+‌​)?(?:\s*k)?` block, but you can further experiment with `/(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?(?:\s*k)?)(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\g<1>)?/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a bit more optional groups instead of consecutive optional atoms, and use `[,.]` character class instead of `\.` to allow 2 separators, and `\p{Pd}` to match any dashes:

```
/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s*k)?(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+‌​)*(?:\s*k)?)?/i
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/x8qkXnUxUB)

If you want to make it more precise, the `(?:[.,]\d+)*` should be split into `(?:\.\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?`

```
/\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*k)?(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*k)?)?/i
```

**Details**:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - 0+ sequences of `.` or `,` with 1 or more digits after
- `(?:\s*k)?` - an optional sequence of 0+ whitespace + `k` / `K`
- `(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+‌​)?(?:\s*k)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*` - any dash (`\p{Pd}`) or `to` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d+‌​)*(?:\s*k)?` - see above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I think if there is a number like 500,000.56 the regex wont match properly

Comment: Then, replace `?` with `*`: `/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?:\s*k)?(?:\s*(?:\p{Pd}|to)\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+‌​)*(?:\s*k)?)?/i`

Comment: Yes that will do the trick. But ideally it should be something like \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?

Comment: That depends on what you preach: most like short and readable patterns even if they are a bit imprecise, others like outmost precision. I tried to follow the first approach here, but it is up to you to choose. Actuall, that should read as `(?:\.\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?` - *0 or more* occurrences of `.` + 1 or more digits and then 1 or 0 occurrences of `.` + 1 or more digits

Comment: @Vas: This would reject i.e. `1000` as a valid number. This would be acceptable if the requirement is that 3-digit-groups **must** be separated by a comma.  The OP didn't elaborate on this issue. It is also not clear, whether, if a comma appears, there MUST be exactly 3-digit groups. This is a cultural convention (depending on the country, `12.245,37` or `4,6145.25` might be considered legal numbers). I think the requirements need to be specified more precisely, before one can recommend a useful regexp.

Comment: Ok thank you for the reply and explaining. Also I think 600,000-700,000 seems to capture 600,000-700. Based on your new suggestion for ,. it works properly.